# cpanel XML API 404 error

Tags: php, xml, cpanel, whm

Had a look at quite a few posts on stack and the cpanel forum but still cant seem to find a solution.

Im trying to retreive information via an api call but it just always seems to fail. I know its to do with the url 404'ing but not sure how to fix.

I am using the the XMl API class:
https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/

The code I have is:

```
$this->load->library('xmlapi');

$xmlapi = new xmlapi(XMLAPI_HOST);
$xmlapi->password_auth(CPANEL_USER, CPANEL_PASSWORD);

$xmlapi->set_debug(1);



echo '<pre>';
print_r($xmlapi->accountsummary(CPANEL_USER));
echo '</pre>';
```

The above outputs the xml array. In the error_notice it says:

```
HTTP error 404, The requested page was not found.
```

Thats fine. So I echo out the url it uses which 404's:
http://mysite.co.uk:2082/xml-api/accountsummary

The cpanel docs are a little awkward to navigate but just cant find anything on the actual url structure, besides its the class that compiles the url. ive tried adding www, tried an ip etc but no idea why its erroring.

Also if it helps im accessing a normal cpanel account, not a WHM admin and its through http.

Thanks for reading, any help guidance on getting it working would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried accessing the url directly in the browser

Comment: Yep done this, no luck. Just errors out :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are experiencing is that you are attempting to use the accountsummary function from cPanel ports (2082/2083).  The accountsummary function is limited to the administrator accounts since this function is designed to provide administrative api level access for pulling account information from any user on the server.

To access the accountsummary api, you will need to call the accountsummary api from the following url:

```
https://$SERVER_IP:2087/xml-api/accountsummary?user=$USERNAME
```

You will need to replace $SERVER_IP and $USERNAME with their respective values.

- http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/ShowAccountInformation